# android-sdk on debian linux with arm processor

Tags: java, android, linux, debian

Running System: Debian on Raspberry PI 3

I found a package containing the android-sdk for armhf processors.

After a full installation i run into an error executing "android".
It tells me that there were a missing swt.jar in my ANDROID_SWT path.

I searched some hours and finally found the "libswt-gtk-4-java" package which contains an swt4.jar

long story short, i placed the .jar in the ANDROID_SWT folder and got a message that it is a 64bit file and i'm running a 32bit jdk installation.

straight to the end, i downloaded the 64bit version of java [Oracle Download](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and tried to register it with the update-alternative system described [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Java/Installation/Oracle_Java/Java_8/)

now it is not possible to complete the instructions because in my jdk-version is no "javaws" folder/file.

Trying to ignore this and running the command "android" without an javaws alternative registered i get an error explaining me that there are missing files.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display 
>   ......

My questions:

1. Does anyone know were i'll find a swt.jar (32bit)
2. Am i doing something wrong installing java jdk
3. Any other mistakes in my way to install the android-sdk